# MediaElement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

im having a little issue here. I have MediaElement.js set on my project.

It is working perfect in Firefox for Mac, but on Firefox for Windows, it display a text **Download File** and dont render the player.

How this can be possible? I mean, if it's working on FF for Mac, why it couldnt play on Windows?

Thanks for replying!

Comment: what filetype of that media? and what firefox versions

Comment: What format is the file? Are you sure you have the specific MIME type set to be supported by your web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely related to an error that just renders the video file as a link. I would debug the javascript and see if it is throwing an error and work from there.

Comment: Figured it out. Flash wasnt installed properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue.  In my case, the incorrect resource type was being passed in - application/octet-stream instead of video/wmv